# Why this question is returning 0 for every case( Leetcode question : Best time to sell and Buy a stock)?

Tags: python-3.x, math

`for Every test Case it is giving 0

```
class Solution:
    def maxProfit (self, prices: List [ int ]) -> int:
     prices1 = prices .sort(reverse=True)
    if prices==[]:
       return 0
    if prices1 == prices:
       return 0
    else:
    temp = prices .index (min(prices))
    prices = prices[ temp : len(prices)]
    return max(prices)-min(prices)
```

0

[7,1,5,3,6,4] for this output should be 5 but is is showing 0`

Comment: First, you should fix the indentation. Second explain the problem by giving some description. Not all have access to Leetcode.

Comment: What do you expect from this statement - ```prices1 = prices .sort(reverse=True)```

Comment: When you sort a list with the .sort() method, that list is sorted and stored in the same variable. Therefore, you have a sorted list in both the "price" and "price1" variables.

Comment: And a tip: use understandable variable names so that you don’t get confused later in them, and it’s easier for others to understand their purpose. I understand that this is your personal code, but it's better to develop this habit as early as possible :)

Comment: And it makes no sense to cut the list like this: prices[ temp : len(prices)]. If you write prices[ temp : ] it will be the same.